# Optimize the use of Generic Repository using linq to sql c#

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I've Generic Repository Class like this:

```
public class Repository : IDisposable
{
    public  static DataContext context { get; set; } 
    public static void Insert<T>(T item) where T : class
    {
        try
        { 
            var table = context.GetTable<T>(); 
            table.InsertOnSubmit(item);
            context.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    } 

    public void Dispose()
    {
        context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Above one is my Generic Class for Inserting Entity using Linq to sql.
I've total 10 entities in my datacontext and i'm writing 10 Insert methods like this(Example i'm providing 3 methods).

```
public void AddStudent(Student st)
{ 
    Repository.Insert<Student>(st);
}

public void AddEmployee(Employee emp)
{ 
    Repository.Insert<Employee>(emp);
}

public void AddStudent(Product prod)
{ 
    Repository.Insert<Product>(prod);
}
```

like this I've 10 methods. is there a way to optimize this code. like this 
I want to create a class with Add method and i'll  use this add method entire my app where ever it is required.

```
public class Class1
{
    public void Add(Table table)
    {
        Repository.Insert<Table>(table);
    }    
}
```

I want to use like this  `Class1 cls1 = new Class1(); cls1.Add(StudentObject);`

can please suggest the way to implement class.

Comment: The `try\catch` block in `Repository` is completely useless as it stands.

Comment: What's wrong with generic method `Add<T>` ? Also usually you have generic repositories, not generic methods.

Comment: @DanielKelley thanks for reply. so what is the good way to use this.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy - nothing wrong in that it is working fine. I want to minimize add methods in my class. so is there a way to do this

Comment: There's no point in catching an exception only to rethrow it.  It's identical to not having the try/catch block there at all.

Comment: You could create a `StudentRepository` and an `EmployeeRepository` to store each aggregate root (check out entity aggregate roots in DDD).  Generic repositories are also a bit of an anti-pattern.

Comment: @jsiklie I think you doesnt know what "Generic" means yet, Add<T> is more than sufficient why use AddEmployee when you can just use Add<T>(T item) { Repository.Insert<T>(item) }

Answer (score 1):

You could define a generic class rather than just a method:

```
public class Repository<T> : IDisposable
    {
        public  static DataContext context { get; set; } 

        public static void Insert(T item)
        {
            var table = context.GetTable<T>(); 
            table.InsertOnSubmit(item);
            context.SubmitChanges();      
        } 

        public void Dispose()
        {
            context.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

And you then get the following, rather than all the additional methods:

```
var repo = new Repository<Product>();
repo.Insert(aProduct);
```

Comment: I've total 10 entities in my datacontext. i'm using single business class so I've to create 10 repository objects like this.so  is that correct? Is there a way to write more reusable code.

Comment: @jsiklie - Sorry, I'm not really understanding your requirements from that comment.  Do you have a method in a business class that needs to insert 10 different types of entities?

Comment: Exactly. i need to insert 10 different types of entities.

Comment: Will one of these entities be the 'root' of the object graph?  I'm assuming they are all related at some level.

Comment: some tables having some relationship with each other. some tables are independent